# Do any US states require online businesses to register and pay tax?

Tags: united-states, business, online

If an Internet services company (a search engine, social network etc.) is registered in say California or Delaware, but offers its services throughout the US, do any other US states require it to be registered in them and pay any taxes ([franchise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franchise_tax), income, sales etc.)?

Comment: Why limit it to online businesses? Many traditional businesses also offer services throughout the country.

Comment: @Barmar Because the lack of brick-and-mortar presence in the states could possibly make difference, I don't know. Only interested in online.

Answer (score 5):

[*South Dakota v. Wayfair, Inc.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Dakota_v._Wayfair,_Inc.), 585 U.S. ___ (2018) held that states may require retailers to collect and remit sales tax for sales made in the state, even if the seller has no physical presence in the state.

Many states now required this. [Stripe.com summarizes](https://stripe.com/guides/introduction-to-us-sales-tax-and-economic-nexus#:%7E:text=The%20term%20economic%20nexus%20refers,has%20different%20laws%20and%20rules.):

- all states that collect sales tax now do so even for sellers with only an economic nexus, provided a threshold is met
- the threshold in most states is $100,000 in sales or 200 transactions over 12 months

Comment: A very fine distinction: this does not mean that these businesses have to *pay* taxes to those states; they only have to collect taxes owed by their customers.

Comment: This answer is specifically about sales tax. The question is more broad.

Comment: @bdb484 What body do they have to _pay_ the states' taxes to then?

Comment: They don't pay; as Jen noted, they remit.